# How to convert int type OBJECTID to ObjectID type recognised by ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

I have an ordinary table with OBJECTID column (type of int) in a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I need to store it in an ArcSDE geodatabase instance running on top of the SQL Server. The thing is how to make the OBJECTID field to the esri-compliant Object ID type so that feature operations through Feature Server can be applied down the track?

Comment: I searched out a solution but still could not get it work. How to get "sdetable -o register" command work with SQL Server on MS SQL Management Studio? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may like to use following command:

`sdetable -o register -t <table>
[{-c <row_id_column> -C {SDE|USER} } | {-C NONE} ]
[-k <config_keyword>]
[-i <service> | <port#> | <direct connection>] [-s <server_name>] 
[-D <database_name>] -u <DB_user_name> [-p <DB_user_password>] [-q]`

However while you are at it, make sure that you specify `-C ObjectID` and `-C User` which will tell SDE that the `ObjectID` is the unique Id field and it is maintained by the user. You may like to refer to command reference for more info on this.

Hope this helps!